# Need to display user details after login in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

```
public function index(){
      $user =  DB::table("users")->where("id", 1)->get();
      return view('home',['user'=>$user]);
   }
```

Here the "id=1" has to be changed and should display the current logged in user details.

Comment: use `\Auth::id()` to get current logged in user's id

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Laravel's default login implementation, simply use `Auth::user()` to get the logged in user model.

```
public function index(){
    $user = \Auth::user();
    return view('home', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using default authentication system of laravel
then you can simply use `Auth::id()` `Auth::user()->id`or `Auth::user()->name` or `Auth::user()->email` directly in the view.
you can get all your users table fields in view just using `Auth::user()->field_name`

if you want to use controller then you can use the below code

```
public function index(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('home',compact('user'));
}
```

and using query builder:

```
public function index(){
      $user =  DB::table("users")->where("id", Auth::user()->id)->get();
      return view('home',compact('user'));
   }

public function index(){
      $user =  DB::table("users")->where("id", Auth::id())->get();
      return view('home',compact('user'));
   }
```

Note: make sure to import the Auth class in your controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Answer (score 0):

Here No need to do anything in the model. just do something like this.

To get id-

`{{ Auth::id() }}` in the blade.

OR

```
{{ Auth::user()->id }}
```

To get name

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

And to get other detail

```
{{ Auth::user()->databaseFieldName }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way im using and it works

```
 @auth
   {{{ isset(Auth::user()->name) ? Auth::user()->name : Auth::user()->email }}}
   <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"> Logout </a>
 @else
   <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
   <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
 @endauth
```